# could not attach to pid on xcode 8.1 simulator

Tags: xcode, simulator

I have been having this error:

```
could not attach to pid
```

From Xcode for about 3 days now. The weird thing is during the 3 weeks it got me to finish this project I have had no issues with running the project on the simulator, but after I successfully added provisioning profile I have been having this issue.

I have tried all other solutions posted on here and other forums but all don't seem to work for me. I am using Xcode 8.1 and macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a painstaking research i discovered the whole error started from when the code refused to compile after adding facebook sdk, so i changed the mach-o type to dynamic libraries thats when the code compiled but now refused to attach to emulator so i reveresed my actions and got the normal compile error i was getting before which was a Arch-64 error so i added that architecture to my target and problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Go to XCode, Preferences,.. and click on location Tab.

Go to DerivedData folder and delete all folders in it.

Then try running Xcode again.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the content and settings, like this in the menu:

[image]

Also, when I have the issue I can usually re-run the app a few times and it works.

Comment: I just tried to reset the content settings a few times now and still the same thing. Is it possible the error may be coming from my build settings? or is there any specific thing that usually generates this error? thanks

Comment: @Smilecs Not that I know of. Sorry. I  am going to leave my answer incase others find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:
Finder->Go->Go to the folder copy text below add paste, delete all and install xcode again:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
~/Library/Application Support/Xcode
~/Library/Developer/Xcode
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
```